# Arrow sintax in a React class component

Tags: reactjs, methods, components

I was wandering, why the showMore method works only if I use the arrow sintax, if I don't use it, and click on the button, the console display an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined", but work when the method(without arrow sintax) is called in componentDidMount() for the first time.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Jokes extends Component{
    state = { joke: []};

    showMore = () =>{
            fetch('https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_ten')
            .then(response =>  response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({ joke: json }));  
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    this.showMore();
    }

    render(){
        const JOKES = this.state.joke;        
        return(
            <div>
                {JOKES.map(JOKE =>{
                    return(
                        <p key={JOKE.id}>{ JOKE.setup}<em>{JOKE.punchline}</em></p>
                    )
                })}                
                <button onClick={this.showMore}>Show more jokes</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Jokes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an arrow function so that `showMore` is correctly scoped to the React Class, and not the click handler. When using the arrow function, `this` is the React Component, which will have setState etc. When you do not use the arrow function, `this` will be the element that was selected

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions